# PhoneGap logo to be removed while launching IOS app

Tags: iphone, html, ios, xcode, cordova

IOS app development with phone-gap.
When the app is installed/launched for the first time, PhoneGap logo(with text- 'iphone retina') appears which needs to be removed. I am not able to figure-out whether it is an image or css, where it resides and how it can be removed.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the current Default.png file and put your own **Default.png file (320x480 for noraml)**.  For ratina image keep **Default@2x.png (640x960) file**.

Comment: i deleted both the images from splash folder, but still the image appears. i guess it is in some other folder.

Comment: clean and re-build your project...also delete app from simulator.. n try

Comment: After I modify or delete Default.png, my app won't install (3/4 of the way through install I get the generic "Unable to Download App" error). Any ideas?